# Removed account from Mackbook, how can I add it back again?

Tags: time-machine, mail.app, google-apps

I had a mail account set up for a client, but my work with them is done.  They use Google Apps so set me up an account there to use, and once my part was done they removed my account.  No problems there as all the emails I had sent or received were still on my local computer (many of my sent emails in particular had value to me as they were brainstorming and ideas, etc.).

Unfortunately I didn't think it through, and removed the account from my computer which of course meant that all the emails are gone from Mail.app.

On my phone however, the account is still present along with all my sent mails etc.

Is there any way to get the account back on my MacBook, without being able to log into the account itself (since it's been turned off by the client)?  I do have TM backups of the machine but don't know what I would be looking for to recover the account.

Comment: Completely untested, as I don't have a deleted account… Select your 'global' inbox in Mail, then from the Time Machine menu. "Enter Time Machine'. TM gives you a very similar interface as though you did it from Finder, but it's in your Mailboxes. I've done that for deleted mails, never deleted inboxes.

Comment: By "global inbox" do you mean the "v5" folder (in my case anyway, the number has incremented over time as the OS has updated)?  If so that contains ALL the emails and attachments for all of my numerous accounts and is over 8GB in size.  I don't really want to have to restore something so big and sift through it, but I can't figure out how to find just the stuff related to the account in question.

Comment: Nope. I mean right there in Mail, not in Finder. Don't go digging, let TM do that.

Comment: Oh!  OK I get it now.  Wow I would never have imagined that would work, always thought Time Machine access was strictly from Finder.  It's presenting me a TM view of my Inboxes but the windows are all in the wrong places and wrong sizes... something definitely doesn't seem to be working properly here.  But still I now have something new to explore so, thank you! EDIT:  I tried restoring what looks like the deleted mailbox (it had no name, just blank) but when I hit restore I got bounced out of TM and nothing happened at all. No prompt to save anything, just... nothing.  =(